# how to organize outgoing api request urls in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, microservices, httparty

I have an application in rails that make request to other microservices using httparty. Other microservices are also written in Rails. Right now, i hard coded all the api urls used in httparty, what will be a more elegant way to organize them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a great question, although it's way too broad to be answered meaningfully here without more specifics on the problem you're solving.

However, if I were you, I'd start by reading the source code for existing API libraries. It's a fantastic way to learn about API design principles from very practical examples in products you likely use every day.

Personally, I've found that the Stripe Ruby SDK (https://github.com/stripe/stripe-ruby specifically, `lib/stripe/api_operations`), the Slack Ruby SDK (https://github.com/dblock/slack-ruby-client), AWS Ruby SDK (https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ruby though this one's pretty big), and Github Ruby SDK (https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ruby) are all well designed and worth studying.